# Laravel: How to find the right blade master template?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

To extend a blade template you have to write

```
@extends('folder.template_name')
```

This works for standard installation.

I've created a module for the backend and now I can't use my module template because Laravel catches the first record and that is the standard view folder.

My structure looks like this:

```
app
-- modules
-- modules\backend
-- modules\backend\views
-- modules\backend\views\layouts\master.blade.php
-- views
-- views\layouts\master.blade.php
```

So when I'm in the backend and try to display my template:

```
// app\modules\backend\views\page\index.blade.php
@extends('layouts.master')
```

Laravel renders the app\views\layouts\master.blade.php instead of
app\modules\backend\views\layouts\master.blade.php

I've tried many names inside that @extends e.g.

```
@extends('app\modules\backend\views\layouts\master')
@extends('app.modules.backend.views.layouts.master')
@extends(base_path(). '\app\modules\backend\views\\' . 'layouts.master')
```

Nothing works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While using a package or autoloaded module, referring to it's resources is done using the double colon notation. In your case, to access the module's master template you need to use

```
@extends('backend::layouts.master')
```

These conventions are described in the docs, for further info please refer to

[Laravel 4 package conventions](http://laravel.com/docs/packages#package-conventions)

Comment: That is the solution. It works!!!
Can you tell me please where I can find more about this?
Do you have any sources about that?

Comment: that is the notation that you use in other places (View::make , Config::get, etc.) to denote that you are reffering to a package or module so I thought it might work also for your case. I am not sure if this info is listed anywhere in the documentation...

Comment: I see it is already updated into the docs, I edited my answer to include this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure /app/config/view.php has a path entry for where those views are located.

I.E.

```
'paths' => array(__DIR__.'/../views'),
```

To

```
'paths' => array(
    __DIR__.'/../views',
    __DIR__.'/../modules/backend/views'
),
```

or whatever represents your actual path.

From here you might want to look into doing the view folder loading via another mechanism if your views are in dynamically generated folders. Maybe a module::boot event that adds the module path to the view paths array? Just an idea.